# What is the order of elements obtained from Realm query?

Tags: realm, realm-java

When executing `findAll()` or `findAllAsync()` query in Realm, without explicit sorting, such as:

```
RealmResults<MyRealmObject> results = realm.where(MyRealmObject.class).findAll();
```

**what is the order of elements accessible through the `RealmResults` object?**

- Is it ordered by `@PrimaryKey` if there is one? If so, is it ascending or descending?
- Is it the order in which the objects were inserted in the first place?
- Is it random?
- Is it nondeterministic?

Also, is this **realm-core** or platform specific, for example does the behavior differ between **realm-java** and **realm-cocoa?**

Comment: It's not deterministic because if you delete something then the order can change. Until you delete something, it's order of insertion; then who knows! The core is the same, the bindings are different; and `realm-cocoa` has integrated more of `realm-object-store` than `realm-java` did.